# Basic Servlet doesn't work

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I tried to create a simple servlet from the book, but to no avail.

I use GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2, jdk1.7.0_10, Notepad.

**root\WEB-INF\classes\net\ensode\glassfishbook\formhandling\FormHandlerServlet.class :**

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook.formhandling;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class FormHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        String enteredValue;
        enteredValue = request.getParameter("enteredValue");
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter printWriter;
        try
        {
            printWriter = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.println("<p>");
            printWriter.print("You entered: ");
            printWriter.print(enteredValue);
            printWriter.print("</p>");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.println("<h2>");
            printWriter.println("If you are reading this, your application server is good to go!");
            printWriter.println("</h2>");
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**root/web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>dataentry.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>FormHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
net.ensode.glassfishbook.formhandling.FormHandlerServlet
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FormHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/formhandlerservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**root/dataentry.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=UTF-8">
<title>Data Entry Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="formhandlerservlet">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Please enter some text:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="enteredValue" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I create the WAR file by the following command in the console:

```
cd e:\root\
jar cvf formhandling.war *
```

Next, I copy my WAR file into the ‘autodeploy’ directory.

```
The link: http://localhost:8080/formhandling/
gives me the error: HTTP Status 404, description - The requested resource () is not available.

The link: http://localhost:8080/formhandling/dataentry.html
gives me the error: HTTP Status 404, description - The requested resource () is not available.

The link: http://localhost:8080/formhandling/formhandlerservlet
gives me the right response: “If you are reading this, your application server is good to go!”
```

It seems that Glassfish couldn’t find the **dataentry.html** file, but I copy all code from the book and don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you compile your Java file? That steps seems to be missing. Also: try looking at the Glassfish logs.

Comment: @jan.vdbergh, yes, I compiled it and GET request works! Logs: [AutoDeploy] Successfully autodeployed : E:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\formhandling.war

Answer (score 0):

The code from the book didn't work because dataentry.html was created in the folder WEB-INF, I correct this mistake:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/dataentry.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now, I have my html file in the root directory. It works.